# Unable to send keyboard events to Bluetooth HID connected device

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, hid

I am able to connect to the Bluetooth HID device successfully and able to control the paired device home button and navigation buttons.
But unable to send Keyboard key events properly to the HID device. When I am typing something in the host device, the HID device responding with random actions.

I have the following code for the connection with descriptors array,

```
override fun onServiceConnected(profile: Int, proxy: BluetoothProfile?) {
            if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HID_DEVICE) {
                mBtHidDevice = proxy as BluetoothHidDevice

                val sdp = BluetoothHidDeviceAppSdpSettings(
                    "HidControl",
                    "Android HID Joystick",
                    "Android",
                    0xC0.toByte(),
                    descriptor
                )
           }
       }
```

The descriptor array is as below,

```
private val descriptor = byteArrayOf( // HID descriptor
    0x09,  // bLength
    0x21,  // bDescriptorType - HID
    0x11, 0x01,  // bcdHID (little endian - 1.11)
    0x00,  // bCountryCode
    0x01,  // bNumDescriptors (min 1)
    0x22,  // bDescriptorType - Report
    0x30, 0x00,  // wDescriptorLength (48)
    // Report descriptor
    0x05, 0x01,  // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x06,  // USAGE (Key board)
    0xa1.toByte(), 0x01,  // COLLECTION (Application)
    0xa1.toByte(), 0x00,  //   COLLECTION (Physical)
    0x05, 0x09,  //     USAGE_PAGE (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,  //     USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x04,  //     USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 4)
    0x15, 0x00,  //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,  //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x75, 0x01,  //     REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x95.toByte(), 0x04,  //     REPORT_COUNT (4)
    0x81.toByte(), 0x02,  //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0x75, 0x04,  //     REPORT_SIZE (4)
    0x95.toByte(), 0x01,  //     REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x81.toByte(), 0x03,  //     INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
    0x05, 0x01,  //     USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x30,  //     USAGE (X)
    0x09, 0x31,  //     USAGE (Y)
    0x15, 0x81.toByte(),  //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f,  //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08,  //     REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95.toByte(), 0x02,  //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81.toByte(), 0x02,  //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0xc0.toByte(),  //   END_COLLECTION
    0xc0.toByte() // END_COLLECTION
)
```

Code to send keyboard events to the target device is below

```
override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    Log.d("Key Codes ", "$keyCode + event: $event")
    for (btDev in mBtHidDevice!!.connectedDevices) {

        mBtHidDevice!!.sendReport(
            btDev, 0, byteArrayOf(event!!.keyCode.toByte())
        )
        mBtHidDevice!!.sendReport(
            btDev, 0, byteArrayOf(
                0
            )
        )
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)

}
```

Please suggest if I am missing anything here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not a Kotlin or bluetooth expert, so I can't provide an actual answer, but I think a few things need attention: 1. The BluetoothHidDeviceAppSdpSettings device subclass should be 0x00 (not 0xc0.toByte()), 2. I would remove all instances of .toByte() because they don't do anything (converting a byte to a byte), 3. The HID report descriptor appears to be for a joystick with 4 buttons - so I would replace it with a report descriptor for a keyboard. An example is given in Appendix E of https://usb.org/sites/default/files/hid1_11.pdf (the official USB device class specification).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Keyboard Usage Page.

The logical minimum and logical maximum that I see is only from 1 to 4. You wanted those USAGEs alone?

Refer to HID usage table https://www.usb.org/document-library/hid-usage-tables-122

There is a Keyboard use case in the appendix. You can refer to that.